# Zen Grids not displaying correctly in IE8

Tags: html, css, zend-framework, internet-explorer-8

I have been attempting to build out this 6 column grid system using Zen Grids. I think it looks great in Firefox but when I try to pull it up in IE8 it does not pull over my styles or the grid and it pushes everything over to the left. I've tried adding the conditional statements in the header and a few other zen statements that I read on various sites it recommended I add and none work. Here is a link: http://spenry.mydevryportfolio.com/corpu/

Please help

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support flex, media queries and lots more, what are you expecting with a very old browser? I use respond.js for media query support and then use modernizr to detect flex support and re-write that grid the old way for no-flex

Comment: Awesome!!! I added these two things and now it works perfectly in IE8. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: However, now when I view it on my mobile phone the image placeholders I had in the grid are missing. Any idea what would have caused that? Would the js i added cause this?